# How come CodeIgniter's img tag doesn't fill the "src" properly?

Tags: codeigniter

My code is as follows:

```
$image_array = array(
    "src"   =>  base_url() . "img/ajax-bar_loader.gif"
    );
echo img( $image_array );
```

But when I debug in FireFox, the tag is:

```
<img original="http://www.mysite.com/img/ajax-bar_loader.gif" style="">
```

I'm not really sure where that "original" tag came from, but it doesn't render my images. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only passing the src attribute, have you tried:

```
echo img(base_url() . "img/ajax-bar_loader.gif");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need the base_url() part. This should suffice.

```
$image_array = array(
    "src"   =>  "img/ajax-bar_loader.gif"
    );
echo img( $image_array );
```

For more, go here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img